# How to filter response of a JAX-RS service?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I got the following value object:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Movie{
  public String name;
  public Date releaseDate;
  public List<Actors> actors;
}
```

and i got the following service

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Movie> moviesByYear(int year){
//return all movies by year
}
```

The movies are searched in the database by some ORM framework. My question is: I want to filter the response, to not return the actors list (because this field is not relevant, and makes the response larger). Of course I can

```
for(Movie movie: movies){
  movie.actors = null;
}
```

but this will escalate quickly if I want to remove multiple fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never want to include the `actors` field in your response, you can annotate the field with `@XmlTransient`. See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) for more details.

Otherwise, you could wrap the `Movie` object into a wrapper object that doesn't expose the `actors` field.

Answer (score 0):

If the service has no method that does it, you'll have to change the service code itself.